# Encrypt Persian Messages

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I have a problem with my new messenger.
I want to encrypt users messages.
If They enter Persian words, I can't encrypt it.

[This is the picture of messenger's main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSA0s.png)

These undefined symbols (like : �) are my problem
How I can handle it?

my encryption code

```
function encrypt($message){
    // Store a string into the variable which
// need to be Encrypted
    $simple_string = $message;

// Store the cipher method
    $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";

// Use OpenSSl Encryption method
    $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
    $options = 0;

// Non-NULL Initialization Vector for encryption
    $encryption_iv = '1234567891011121';

// Store the encryption key
    $encryption_key = "SparkSocial";

// Use openssl_encrypt() function to encrypt the data
    $encryption = openssl_encrypt($simple_string, $ciphering,
        $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);
    return $encryption;
}

function decrypt($code){
    // Store the cipher method
    $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";

    // Non-NULL Initialization Vector for decryption
    $decryption_iv = '1234567891011121';

// Store the decryption key
    $decryption_key = "SparkSocial";

    $options = 0;

    $decryption=openssl_decrypt ($code, $ciphering,
        $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv);

    return $decryption;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Quick run of your code shows, no problems.

```
function encrypt($message){
// Store a string into the variable which
// need to be Encrypted
    $simple_string = $message;

// Store the cipher method
    $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";

// Use OpenSSl Encryption method
    $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
    $options = 0;

// Non-NULL Initialization Vector for encryption
    $encryption_iv = '1234567891011121';

// Store the encryption key
    $encryption_key = "SparkSocial";

// Use openssl_encrypt() function to encrypt the data
    $encryption = openssl_encrypt($simple_string, $ciphering,
        $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);
    return $encryption;
}

function decrypt($code){
    // Store the cipher method
    $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";

    // Non-NULL Initialization Vector for decryption
    $decryption_iv = '1234567891011121';

// Store the decryption key
    $decryption_key = "SparkSocial";

    $options = 0;

    $decryption=openssl_decrypt ($code, $ciphering,
        $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv);

    return $decryption;
}

$a = encrypt("الف");
$b = decrypt($a);
echo $b;
```

Output:

```
الف
```

So without further information, I would recommend you to look at [Charset UTF-8 still shows special signs as question mark](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78925/charset-utf-8-still-shows-special-signs-as-question-mark)